# RingTone Manager with default Vibration

Tags: android

I am developing Calling App. On incoming Call I have to play Default Rintone and Vibrate phone as per default settings done by user in phone.

I am able to play Ringtone with Ringtone Manager.

```
            Uri ringtonerUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(apprtcContext, ringtonerUri);
        ringTone.play();
```

1. How to Vibrate as per default settings if user put phone on
   Vibrator?
2. How to Mute ringtone if User presses the Down Volume
       button ?

Answer (score 1):

Refering to: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#274

The default vibrate pattern is

```
static final long[] DEFAULT_VIBRATE_PATTERN = {0, 250, 250, 250};
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you.

Comment: Read the question properly before answering. The OP is not asking for vibration pattern, rather how to vibrate the phone.